# Image not loading in page on WAMP localhost 403 forbidden error, but clicking its link works

Tags: image, localhost, wamp

I have the following code in my localhost project in WAMP

```
<img src="/imgs/quickstartVideo.jpg" width="357" height="200" alt="quick start video">
```

The image won't appear - console says "403 (forbidden)". However, if I right click to view the page source, and click the image's link, the image appears.

The page loads js and css files that are using the same sort of relative URL.

Why does it tell me it's forbidden, yet lets me load it when I click it? How do I get it to just load please?

My dir structure is:

```
c:\wamp
c:\wamp\www
c:\wamp\www\imgs
c:\wamp\www\js (js files are loading fine)
```

UPDATE: it's displaying correctly in MS Edge, but not Chrome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved -the issue was an IfModule mod_rewrite I'd set up in htaccess to stop image hotlinking on my production domain. Commented it out for localhost development, and, funny enough, my images are working again.